# Manage multiple following positional argument with argparse

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse, args

I'm using this lib for parsing arguments in python : https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html

So far I have this:

```
prog arg1 [-s arg2 [arg2 ...]] [-m arg3 [arg3 ...]]
```

And I want this:

```
prog arg1 -s arg2 [arg2 ...] -m arg3 [arg3 ...]
```

Here is my python code:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('path', type=str,
                    help="path used for the generation of the rouge files")
parser.add_argument('-s', '--systems', type=str, nargs='+',
                    help="path to the systems generated summary files")
parser.add_argument('-m', '--models', type=str, nargs='+',
                    help="path to the reference summary files")
args = parser.parse_args()
print args
```

The problem is when you call the program without the optional arguments, it doesn't give an error (too few arguments). I want my optional arguments to be obligatory, but when you make the following call, the parser doesn't figure out which kind of args are involved...

For exemple with the following code:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('arg1', type=str, nargs='+')
parser.add_argument('arg2', type=str, nargs='+')
parser.add_argument('arg3', type=str, nargs='+')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

And the following call:

```
python test.py arg1 arg1 arg1 arg2 arg2 arg3 arg3
```

I got this:

```
Namespace(arg1=['arg1', 'arg1', 'arg1', 'arg2', 'arg2'], arg2=['arg3'], arg3=['arg3'])
```

For sure here is the format of this prog:

```
prog arg1 [arg1 ...] arg2 [arg2 ...] arg3
```

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: What is your question? Does this code work?

Comment: This code works, but the arguments are optional. I don't figure out how to make them be kind of obligatory.

Comment: What do you mean by "kind of obligatory". The `nargs='+'` arguments are already required.

Comment: Yeap but the parser doesn't figure out which kind of arguments are involved in the call, that's why I use the flags (-a) but it make them optional, it means that you can make a call without them... :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`optionals` can take a `required=True` parameter.  That may be all you need.

```
 p=argparse.ArgumentParser()
 p.add_argument('-m',nargs='+',required=True)
 p.add_argument('-n',nargs='+',required=True)
 p.print_usage()
```

producing

```
 usage: ipython3 [-h] -m M [M ...] -n N [N ...]
```

As to why:

```
 Namespace(arg1=['arg1', 'arg1', 'arg1', 'arg2', 'arg2'], arg2=['arg3'], arg3=['arg3'])
```

you specified that each of `arg1, arg2, arg3` required 1 or more strings.  It split up the long list accordingly, giving `arg2` and `arg3` each one (which satisfies their requirement), and allocating the rest to `arg1`.  If you are familiar with `regex`, this is equivalent

```
In [96]: re.match('(A+)(A+)(A+)','AAAAAAAAA').groups()
Out[96]: ('AAAAAAA', 'A', 'A')
```

(The parser can't read your mind and allocate all the 'arg2's to `args2` just because the names look similar.:)  )

So if you need to split lists of arguments in a specific way, then `optionals` (flags) is the way to go.  And between `nargs` and `required` you have quite a bit of control over the numbers.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is not possible. Think about it: if you would implement your own argument parsing without `argparse`, how would you determine if a positional argument is the last one of a list of `arg1` arguments, or the first of the `arg2` arguments?

I think the solution you've got know (optional arguments) works fine and is even preferable.

Answer (score 0):

I added require=True and it works, thanks to hpaulj

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('path', type=str,
                    help="path used for the generation of the rouge files")
parser.add_argument('-s', '--systems', type=str, nargs='+', required=True,
                    help="path to the systems generated summary files")
parser.add_argument('-m', '--models', type=str, nargs='+', required=True,
                    help="path to the reference summary files")
args = parser.parse_args()
```

---

```
python summary2rouge.py 
usage: summary2rouge.py [-h] -s SYSTEMS [SYSTEMS ...] -m MODELS [MODELS ...]
                    path
summary2rouge.py: error: too few arguments
```